# iPhone facebook friend with email address

Tags: iphone

How do I fetch the email of my friend programmatically in my facebook applicaiton. If facebook don't provide that functionality then can i provide the permission of my facebook application to get email address? If Yes then how? 
Please can you provide code me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is all easily possible. Just register a Facebook dev account and download their iPhone SDK.